# Как связать таблицу значений с характеристиками?

Tags: база-данных, моделирование

Готовлю аналитическую модель для отображения погоды.
У погоды есть характеристика. К примеру:
10.10.2018 Температура 38 градус, Жарко
10.10.2018 Влажность 98%, очень влажно
Где жарко и влажно эта характеристика погоды. 
Сомнения меня гложат в правильности моей модели, правильно ли я ее смоделировал? как связать Характер погоды с характеристиками каждой метеовеличины? Через общую таблицу или с каждой таблице характеристик как у меня? Прилагаю рисунок.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну если характеристика однозначно определяется значением, то просто таблица, соединяющее диапазон значений с характеристикой. Диапазоны суммарно должны быть покрывающими, чтобы не хардкодить дефолтное значение - т.е. границы должны заходить за разумные (скажем, температура от -300 и до +500, или влажность от -10% до +120%). Ну и связь по `value between lower and higher`.

Comment: @Akina я новичок в этом деле.  1. т.е. оставить таблицу Характер погоды. А таблицу "Характеристика величин" (фиолетовым цветом обозначено) не создавать?   2. Что значит value between lower and higher. Как это показать на схеме? Данные в инете не смог найти.

Comment: У Вас будет (если ориентироваться на выбранный подход) EAV-таблица погоды (Дата-Параметр_ИД-Значение), таблица-словарь параметров (Параметр_ИД, Параметр), и таблица-словарь диапазонов характеристик (Параметр_ИД, Значение_Мин, Значение_Макс, Характеристика). Всё... *Что значит value between lower and higher.* Вы моделируете БД? Значит, общаться с данными будет на языке SQL. Так вот - эта конструкция оттуда.

Comment: @Akina не могу ваш ответ отметить.(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот небольшая заготовка для простого случая, остальное дополните сами, если нужны еще какие-то поля:

Таблица измерений с температурой и влажностью:

```
create table measurement (
  measurement_date date,
  temperature number,
  humidity number);
```

Описания температур:

```
create table temperature_description (
  value_from number,
  value_to number,
  description varchar2(100));
```

Описания влажностей:

```
create table humidity_description (
  value_from number,
  value_to number,
  description varchar2(100));
```

Данные для примера:

```
insert into measurement values (sysdate, 10, 50);
insert into measurement values (sysdate, 20, 99);
insert into measurement values (sysdate, 30, 35);
insert into temperature_description values (0, 15, 'Холодно');
insert into temperature_description values (15, 25, 'Нормально');
insert into temperature_description values (25, 100, 'Жарко');
insert into humidity_description values (0, 40, 'Сухо');
insert into humidity_description values (40, 70, 'Нормально');
insert into humidity_description values (70, 100, 'Влажно');
```

Запрос результатов:

```
select m.measurement_date, m.temperature, td.description, m.humidity, hd.description
  from measurement m
       join temperature_description td on td.value_from < m.temperature 
                                      and td.value_to > m.temperature
       join humidity_description    hd on hd.value_from < m.humidity 
                                      and hd.value_to > m.humidity
```

Надеюсь, принцип понятен.

Посмотреть на sqlfiddle.com: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56ec8/1

**UPD**

Небольшое уточнение (даже два, по мотивам комментариев @Akina).

1. Во-первых, имеет смысл добавить констрейнты для ограничения возможных значений: влажность (в процентах) может быть только от `0` до `100`, температура (в градусах Цельсия) - не ниже `-273,15`.
2. Диапазоны в справочных таблицах должны перекрываться, иначе при джойне значение "пропадет" из выборки. Для этого надо или писать `left join` вместо `join` (хуже для быстродействия, но если данные в справочнике изменятся и диапазоны перестанут перекрываться, это сразу станет видно), или тщательно следить за данными в справочниках. Или еще один вариант - правило "`null` означает отсутствие границы". Тогда в справочник можно вставить, например, для температуры, значения "с ... по" - "100 - `NULL`":

   ```
   insert into temperature_description values (100, null, 'Ваще ад');
   ```

   А условие связи таблиц переписать так:

   ```
   join temperature_description td 
     on td.value_from < coalesce(m.temperature, td.value_from + 1)
    and td.value_to > coalesce(m.temperature, td.value_to - 1)
   ```

Comment: спасибо огромное. Также за ссылку на сервис! Сервис крутой, пригодится в работе! ;)

Comment: `values (0, 15, 'Холодно')` - не очень хорошо, температуры могут быть и отрицательными... как я говорил в комменте к вопросу, лучше что-то типа `values (-300, 15, 'Холодно')`... ну или оставить так и дополнительно `values (-300, 0, 'ППЦ как холодно')`...

Comment: @Kirumit *Сервис крутой, пригодится в работе!* Сервис, конечно, крутой, но тормозит, как девяносто пятые... лучше посмотрите на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk).

Comment: @Akina -300 не бывает ;) (по крайней мере, по Цельсию, которого я имел в виду; хотя написать можно конечно). Я просто идею показать, дальше он сам разберется, надеюсь.

Comment: Конечно, не бывает. Но такое значение гарантирует, что мы не выскочим за пределы описанного в справочнике диапазона. Тоже, кстати, и с верхней границей неплохо бы проделать... Вы в своём запросе используете INNER JOIN, и если не весь диапазон "накрыт", а значение (пусть и по ошибке) не попадает в диапазоны из справочника - оно просто выпадет из итоговой выборки. Да, наверное, ещё лучше нижний и верхний диапазоны описывать типа `values (-300, -80, 'вероятно, ошибка данных')`.